# What are the supported editing commands for the GNU APL line editor (∇-editor)?

Tags: command, editor, gnu, manual, apl

The [GNU APL documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/apl/apl.html) on the line editor seems to assume one already knows how to use it. I only see mention of what commands/syntax '... are not fully supported in GNU APL'.

Compare with the documentation of [Dyalog's APL ∇-editor](https://help.dyalog.com/18.0/index.htm#Language/Defined%20Functions%20and%20Operators/TradFns/APL%20Line%20Editor.htm), or [MicroAPL](http://www.microapl.com/apl_help/ch_020_020_940.htm).

I'd be willing to prepare a patch to submit for the documentation if anyone has a reference.

Comment: Is that link correct? I see "hex number" there.

Answer (score 4):

The main developer of GNU APL, [Jürgen Sauermann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2971915/j%c3%bcrgen-sauermann), has told me that GNU APL's editor is a clone of APL2's line editor, and thus should support the same commands:

| command | action |
| --- | --- |
| `[⎕]` | display the current whole definition |
| `[⎕2 7 1 …]` | display specific lines |
| `[⎕2-7]` | display a range of lines |
| `[⎕-7]` | display all lines until a specific line |
| `[⎕7-]` | display all lines beginning with a specific line |
| `[7] code` | replace a specific line |
| `[2.1] code` | insert a line between two lines |
| `[∆2 7 1]` | delete specific lines |
| `[∆2-7]` | delete a range of lines |
| `[∆-7]` | delete all lines until a specific line |
| `[∆7-]` | delete all lines beginning with a specific line |
| `[→]` | quit without saving |
| `[2⎕7]` | display line 2 for editing, placing the cursor at position 7 |
| `[2⎕0]` | display line 2 for editing, placing the cursor at the end of the line |

Source: [IBM's APL2 Language Reference](https://www.ibm.com/downloads/cas/ZOKMYKOY#page=384)

Answer (score 1):

See:

APL: The Language and Its Usage;
Polivka & Pakin;
1975

Comment: That may be hard to see. Your post would be significantly improved if you could quote or rephrase the relevant parts.